# Returning a randomly ordered set of distinct objects from a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm using Django 1.3 with Postgresql 8.4 and I've got models like the following (irrelevant stuff removed):

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, through='LocalService')

class LocalService(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
```

I'm trying to get a distinct set of Service objects, filtered by attributes of linked Location objects, and ordered randomly. I tried this first:

```
Service.objects.filter(location__name__icontains='o').distinct().order_by('?')
```

...but that throws this exception:

> DatabaseError: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear
>   in select list

After Googling around, I discovered that to achieve this kind of result at the SQL level, you need to put the DISTINCT and the ORDER BY in separate query levels, ie: use a subquery. If I subquery a DISTINCT set of results I can randomly order them like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT s.*
    FROM profile_service s
    JOIN profile_localservice ls
    ON ls.service_id = s.id
    JOIN profile_location l
    ON ls.location_id = l.id
    WHERE l.name LIKE '%o%'
) as temptable
ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

Do I need to use the Manager.raw() method with this SQL query to get my set of model instances, or is there a simpler way to do this from within the Django API?

Comment: did you try to swap "distinct()" and "order_by()"?

Comment: @akonsu: Yes, I've tried that. It results in the same exception

Comment: If you are trying to make a subquery use `extra()`

Comment: @Pannu: I've tried using the `tables` argument of the `extra()` method. It is working when I simply specify a table name, but whenever I provide a subquery I get a `DatabaseError` exception. Even if the subquery was working out, I understand how I could use this in SELECT and WHERE clauses, but I'm not sure how I would use it as the source for the model instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirements the following might work (and potentially perform better than `ORDER BY Random()`). I'm not sure about Postgresql, but with MySQL randomized ordering on anything but a tiny dataset is really slow.

```
services = list(Service.objects.filter(location__name__icontains='o').distinct())
random.shuffle(services)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I think this will achieve what I'm after.